# Practical difference between TO_DATE and DATEVALUE

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a case.

I have a sheet, the first column of which consists of records like "Some text 28.02.2022 some text". `20.02.2023` is how we write *February, 20* in Europe (compare it with `02/20/2023`, which is how the same date will be typically written in US.)

For each of these records, I need to extract its date, add 10 working days, and put the resulting date in the respective cell of the next column. So it looks like this:

```
|--------------------------------|------------|
| Some text 20.02.2023 some text | 06.03.2023 |
|--------------------------------|------------|
```

To calculate that date, the following formula seems to be sufficient:

```
=WORKDAY(REGEXEXTRACT($A1; "(?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{2,4}"); 10)
```

But then what is the purpose of using `TO_DATE` or `DATE_VALUE`?

Some people even suggest to use them together, like this:

```
=WORKDAY(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT($A1; "(?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{2,4}"))); 10)
```

Sorry if the question sound unprofessionally, but I really tried to figure it out myself for two days.

Comment: Which are you using Excel is NOT Googlesheets...

Comment: Sorry, the `excel` tag is now removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your case both `TO_DATE` and `DATEVALUE` are redundant.**

In order to understand why, you need to keep in mind 4 things.

1. [`TO_DATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239)
   *"Converts a provided number into a date."*
2. [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039)
   *"Converts a provided date string in a known format into a date value."*
3. Dates are numbers
4. Google Sheets is *"smart enough"* to understand when one tries to express a date.

Taking the above into consideration **both conditions are met** (being a number and a date) by just using [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) and [`WORKDAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093059).
Use Google Sheets functions [`ISDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381) and [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296) (as in the image below) to see how they play out.

*(To avoid confusion I took the liberty of changing your working days from +10 to +15)*

[image]